# How do I make Mountain Lion read iMessage texts as they come in?

Tags: macos, messages, text-to-speech

On my MacBook Air in Lion with the iMessages beta I was able to set up iMessage to read all incoming messages automatically with text to speech.

I can't find how to turn that on with Mountain Lion.

I see how I can make it announce or I can select text to have it read out loud but I had it just automatically reading incoming messages out loud with text to speech before.

Answer (score 2):

iMessage->Preferences->Alerts check 'Speak an announcement'

Answer (score -1):

I think you can't do it right now. However if Apple gives iMessage support to Automator you can write an Automator script to do that and when the message arrived you can initiate that script from iMessage->Preferences->Alerts

Comment: iMessages can call an Apple Script when a message arrives so you won't need Automator for that